# Does `std::vector`'s iterator constructor copy the data?

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

Inside a function call, I have a dynamically allocated array that I want to fill a vector with. The context here is that I know I can't return a pointer because it goes out of scope after the return.

My question is about the safety of calling `free` on the created pointer once the vector has been constructed. Does the vector take ownership of the pointer, and therefore responsibility for destruction, or simply copy it's data? My concern is that if I call `free` and the vector's underlying array is the same memory as the original, then I will destroy its contents early.

```
__host__ 
std::vector<float> mult(std::vector<float> x, float scalar) {

    int n = x.size();

    int n_threads = 256;
    int n_blocks = (int)ceil(n / n_threads);
    size_t bytes = n * sizeof(float);    

    float *d_x; // gpu "device" inputs
    float *d_y; // gpu "device" outputs
    float *h_y; // cpu "host" outputs
    
    h_y = (float *)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_x, bytes);
    cudaMalloc(&d_y, bytes);

    cudaMemcpy(d_x, x.data(), bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    mult<<<n_blocks, n_threads>>>(n, d_x, scalar, d_y);
    cudaMemcpy(h_y, d_y, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_y);

    std::vector<float> y(h_y, h_y + sizeof(h_y));

    free(h_y); <<<< CALL IN QUESTION
    return y;
}
```

The docs say:

> (3) range constructor Constructs a container with as many elements as
> the range [first,last), with each element **emplace-constructed** from its
> corresponding element in that range, in the same order.

I googled "emplace constructed" but found no definition of this term, but I feel like this is the key to my question.

Comment: `vector` manages its own memory, that's why it is recommended.  `std::vector<float> y(h_y, h_y + sizeof(h_y));` copies the buffer into the vecotr.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike So it is or is not safe to call `free(h_y)`? My concern is whether or not this will sabatage the vector's memory management by destroying its contents early. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: How can it destroy the contents early?  `free(h_y)` can't happen until `std::vector<float> y(h_y, h_y + sizeof(h_y));` finishes

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike Early in the sense of "after construction, but before the vector can be used, it's data has been lost". My question is whether or not `vector.data(0)` and `h_y` point to the same place in memory. If they do point to the same place, then I imagine that calling free would sabotage the vector's underlying data array.

Comment: They can't point to the same place in memory because **`vector` manages it own memory**.  When you create one it allocates its own memory and it handles it.

Comment: Why do you ever need this pointer and `malloc` and `free`? The vector itself is perfectly capable of providing a buffer you can `cudaMemcpy` data to. Namely `std::vector<float> y(n); cudaMemcpy(y.data(), d_y, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);` And of course `h_y + sizeof(h_y)` is *totally* wrong.

Comment: It's not clear why you need `malloc` at all.

Comment: `h_y` is a pointer to an array, not an array. `sizeof(h_y)` is the size of the pointer which is unrelated to the size of the range you want to copy. You need to add the actual number of elements to `h_y` to get an "end" pointer (presumably `n`).

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike *"When you create one it allocates its own memory"* thank you, this was the answer I was looking for. The phrase "manages its own memory" does not necessarily preclude this, and was the core of my question.

Comment: @rocksNwaves *manages it's own memory* also includes freeing said memory.

Comment: @rocksNwaves It is common C++ terminology that "manages its own memory" implies "allocates its own memory [if it needs to]". Whether or not memory allocations are required, you can assume standard containers will manage it themselves if it needs to. What you seem to be asking is whether `std::vector` depends on the continued validity of the range that was provided to it. Standard C++ containers work with value semantics. They copy the given range. Once you initialized your vector, the original initialization data doesn't need to be maintained.

Comment: Anything allocating using `malloc()` can be safely released using `free()` - exactly once.   The value of `h_y` is obtained from a call of `free()`.  So `free(h_y)` is safe.      However, in C++, it is not necessary at all that you use `malloc()` and `free()` - there are safer alternatives.    There are other bugs in your code as well, including copying more values to a `std::vector` than it has.

Comment: *"I googled 'emplace constructed' but found no definition of this term"* -- Maybe try the words individually instead of treating them as a phrase? There is [a page dedicated to "emplace" in the context of `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) on cppreference.com. (It basically means that no temporary objects will be utilized; construction occurs in-place.) The same site has [a page covering construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). (It basically means that new objects will be created based on the data you provide.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit that is interesting:

```
    // Step 1: Allocate memory.
    float *h_y; // cpu "host" outputs
    h_y = (float *)malloc(n * sizeof(float));


    // Step 2: Copy data from source into allocated memory
    cudaMemcpy(h_y, d_y, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Step 3: Copy data from allocated memory to vector
    //         With a bug.
    std::vector<float> y(h_y, h_y + sizeof(h_y));

    // Step 4: Free Allocated memory.
    free(h_y);
```

Your iniital question? Does "Step 4: free(h_y)" mess with the vectors memory.

Short Answer: No.
Long Answer: Containers (like vector) manage their own memory. So it allocates room and copies the data into this memory. So you should be freeing this memory.

**BUT**: You have a bug:

```
std::vector<float> y(h_y, h_y + sizeof(h_y));
// sizeof(h_y) is the size of the pointer (probably 8 bytes)
// Not the size of the allocated memory.
// So you have only copyied one or two floats into the vector.
```

You probably wanted:

```
std::vector<float> y(h_y, h_y + n);
```

**Emplace Constructed:**

This is just a fancy way of saying that we are going to avoid calling default construtor followed by copy constructor. Instead it will make sure the object in the vector are constructed "in-place" by calling the constructor passing a reference to the each item in the range.

Since you have `float` there is no actual constructor so it is going to simply copy each value from the range directly into the vectors allocated memory.

### What you should be doing:

Don't allocate a temporary buffer. Just make sure the vector is of sufficient size and just copy directly from CUDA into your vector.

```
    // Step 1: Allocate memory (in the vector)
    std::vector<float> y(n);

    // Step 2: Copy data from source into allocated memory
    cudaMemcpy(&y[0], d_y, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Note: &y[0] is the address of the first element in the vector.
    //             vectors are contiguous.
```